# My external monitor no longer works with macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I have just updated to macOS Mojave and suddenly my Benq GL2750H no longer shows the original resolution (1920*1080). I have tried to select it in display options with the option key pressed:the monitor goes black and back to the old (1024*768) resolution. How can I get the original resolution back?

Error messages from console:

```
-[CBDisplayContainerMacOS start]: failed to start
-[BLControl updateDisplaySet:]_block_invoke: failed to start cotainer for display ID 2026497910
-[CBDisplayContainerMacOS setupInternalModules]: Failed to create display module for device ID 1535218053
```

Comment: Try opening the "Console" and checking which errors are being thrown. Most likely the graphics driver is returning that the monitor failed to change to 1920x1080. Sometimes this is solved by unplugging the monitor from the wall and the computer, and connecting again. When a monitor is first connected, the display adapter (GPU) tries to determine the available display layouts via the DDC2B pins (for VGA) or over the HDMI/DisplayPort protocol.

I would also ask whether you can try connecting over HDMI or DisplayPort instead of VGA since some monitors botch one or more protocols.

Comment: Thanks Bill it says: Failed to displayCBDDisplayContainerMacos or something like that. HDMI/VGA all fail.

Comment: Ok, so. Which Mac do you have? How is the monitor connected? When you go to System Information, what does it show for your monitor?

Comment: Are you connected with an HDMI cable, DVI or VGA D-Sub? I’ve confirmed your monitor does 1920x1080 and it’s a pretty decent one.

Comment: Can you grab the exact error messages from console?

Comment: Done see above in the question.

Comment: Can you turn off G-Sync on your monitor? That’s the only thing I can find....

Comment: Which type of cable are you using and which Mac? My best guess is that the monitor is trying to negotiate for faster refresh than your GPU and cable can provide. Turn off the high refresh rate stuff on your monitor and it may be able to run at the high resolution, but you can’t have both high refresh and high resolution.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I’d like to know whether turning off G-Sync fixed this for you.

Comment: I have the same issue after the recent Mojave update.